# Limited Number of Beta Coefficients for 1000 predictors using glm() in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

When I fit a logistic regression in R using `glm()` (I have 1 binary outcome and 1000 predictors). I do not want to reduce my predictors, but `glm()` yields beta coefficients for the first 50 predictors ONLY. However, when I use Python Sklearn, I can get all beta coefficients for all predictors. How to solve this problem? I have to use R, and I cannot do dimension reduction.

Tried in Python and it works. But R does not.

Comment: I don't know what python does there but I would expect such a result from R. I don't think you have enough observations to support such a massive model (I expect you would have run out of memory if you had). I would also expect severe [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) issues and [they are probably the reason for the NA coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385079/11849). What you are doing there seems like nonsense to me.

Comment: Did you try `model$coefficients`. Here `model` is your model's name.

Comment: What is your data size? Also when you say first 50. Do the others dont show up or rather are they NA?

Comment: @Roland I don't understand. I am clear about what I want, and Python can do it but R cannot. You are just ignorant.

Comment: @MetehanGungor Yes I did!

Comment: @Onyambu there are 50 rows and about 1100 columns. I know the dimension is not balance, but that is what I got here.

Comment: Then even python cannot get all the coefficients. You can only get at most 50 coefficients. the rest will be aliased, and also you will have no remaining degrees of freedom to estimate the standard error. Your model matrix is not of full rank

Comment: Think of it this way, if you have 2 unknows with 2 equations, you can solve for the unknowns. In your case you have 1000 unknows with 50 equations. You can only solve 50 of the unknowns. R selects the first 50 and solves for that